# Parse.com segue won`t pass data

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, parse-platform, segue

I have 2 tableviews, both filled with data. Both have segue to detailView.One is filled with animals and second one with countries. I would like to pass data to display from detail with animals to detail with countries according to the country where the animals lives. Already have PFObject in countryDetail.h made because of moving data from countrymainController. NSlog in segue returns me all values correctly from Parse. Thanks for any advice

**animalDetail.m**

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"sendi"])
        {


            ViewControllerimagescale *vco = [segue destinationViewController];
            vco.bomb = self.objc;
        }else{
            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Countries"];
            [query whereKey:@"Wherelive" equalTo:[self.objc objectForKey:@"CouWherelive"]];
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                        ViewControllerDetail *vco = [segue destinationViewController];
                        vco.objc = object;
                        NSLog(@"KOKOE%@", object);

                    }

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }
```

**in countrydetail.h have normally set pfobject**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *objc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is "passing". However, the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` call is asynchronous. That means that your data (`NSArray *objects`) has a very, **VERY** high chance of not being fetched before the destination view controller is presented.

Either use a synchronous call like `findObjects` or call something like `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sendi" sender:nil]` inside the asynchronous block.